# IF statement in R function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to construct a function with an if statement within.
IN the code below,
I basically want to use different contr_x<- makeContrast.. command for different contr_x. ex) If contr_1 is in the input, it will use the first 1f's make constrast command, if contr_2 is in the input, it will use the second if's make constrast command...

But I am running in to the error that says the object contr_1 is not found. I am confused because in my understanding. contr_1 is just an input name, not an object. (not previously defined)

I am attaching the function code and the error below; I 'll appreciate any insight!!

**code**

```
run_limma <- function (model_x, support_x, fit_x,editing_x,contr_x,tmp_x){
  message("starting modeling")
  model_x<-model(support_x, model_x)
  message("starting fitting")
  fit_x<-limma_diff(editing_x, model_x,fit_x)
  message("Making contrasts")
    if (contr_x == "contr_1") {contr_x<-makeContrasts (diseaseAD - diseaseControl, 
                            levels = colnames(coef(fit_x)))
    }
    if (contr_x == "contr_2") {contr_x<-makeContrasts (diseaseAD_MCI - diseaseControl, 
                            levels = colnames(coef(fit_x)))
    }
    if (contr_x == "contr_3") {contr_x<-makeContrasts (diseaseMCI - diseaseControl, 
                            levels = colnames(coef(fit_x)))
    }
    if (contr_x == "contr_4") {contr_x<-makeContrasts (diseasePD - diseaseControl, 
                            levels = colnames(coef(fit_x)))
    }
  message("making tmp file")
  tmp_x<-limma_cont(contr_x, fit_x, tmp_x)
  tmp_x
  }
```

**error**

```r
run_limma(model_1, support_1, fit_1,editing_1,contr_1,tmp_1)
starting modeling
starting fitting
Making contrasts
Error in run_limma(model_1, support_1, fit_1, editing_1, contr_1, tmp_1) : 
  object 'contr_1' not found
```

Comment: In R, `contr_1` is a symbol, usually used to refer to an object. Are you defining `model_1` and `support_1` anywhere? What about the others? I think you should be calling it as `"contr_1"` (quoted).

Comment: no, neither model_1 nor support_1 are defined elsewhere. using "contr_1" as the input still gives me the same error :( I am no sure what the problem is

Comment: Did you try to print(contr_1) in the first linje of the function in order to verify what is the entry?

Comment: [1] "contr_1"  is the printed output when I added print(contr_x) right before the if statements

Comment: as r2evans wrote, the if in the script expects contr_x as a string, but if it is TRUE, then you assign to contr_x the return of a function. May be is better to name one and another different.